# Google Play Game Services. Why Google Cloud for Auth?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-games

I don't find a Google Play Game Services official support where I can send an email so I ask here hoping someone will know the answer.

If I enable Google Play Game Services is required to enable also Google Cloud that is a payment service with some months trial. Is it correct? Will I need to pay after the trial period? I need the Auth service

An app with Google Play Game Services is classified always as Game in the Google Play Store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is the link[1], where you can contact, google play support, they do a community support.

[1]https://support.google.com/googleplay/gethelp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This support is not for developers. It's for normal users that need a refund or have problems in signing in with their smartphone

Comment: @Yoda okey, i see now that the page you were looking for was this one https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp